# select radio button in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm new to XPath and CssSelector.

below is the target html source.

```
<input value="1" name="uji.model.611876.button" type="radio"></input>
```

*611876* is a random number.

I tried with the code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("//input[@value=\"1\"]")).Click();
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("//input[@value='1']")).Click();
```

but the *Unable to locate element* error occurred.

I need help for that situation. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Seems like your XPath is correct but another element is preventing it from being clicked. Are you using a complex widget?

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of complex widget, but I'm using selenium webdriver for firefox in c#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get `ElementNotVisibleException` try to wait some time until target `input` become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[starts-with(@name, \"uji.model.\")][@type=\"radio\"]")));
element.Click();
```

Comment: also, sometimes the element may be blocked by some menu or something overlapping it. This error also occurs in those scenarios.

Comment: @DhirajDas, Yes. Sometimes it happens. If this code  doesn't solve current issue, I'll update it with solution considering your tips

Comment: I tried that. But the webdriver is still waiting after loading. I think my XPath is wrong.

Comment: @8berry, Did you try my `XPath`? In your code you use `XPath` in search by `id`- that's the problem. Also explain what do you mean `webdriver is still waiting after loading`?

Comment: @Andersson yes, but symptoms are same.

Comment: Could you provide with exact exception log that you get using my code?

Comment: the page is fully loaded, but the process does not proceed. I think It is waiting.

Comment: Error log does not appear.

Comment: Do you mean you see something like that http://www.west-wind.com/westwindwebtoolkit/docs/images/ModalDialogWithImage.png after page loaded?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the variable. the error log is _Timed out after 15 seconds_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133325/discussion-between-andersson-and-8berry).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")).Click();
```

Comment: Thank you. But _Element is not visible_ error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JavascriptExecuter` to execute `javascript` code if it is causing problem -

```
IWebElement element= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value=\"1\"]")));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```